# Is there a .dotm template that is Google-friendly?

Tags: google-docs

Keystroke and page-loading delays on Google Docs hamper my productivity in some cases. But I love the platform. Are there changes I can make to a default MS Word template that will make it less likely to have formatting issues when going back and forth from .gdoc format?